# Can you map or transform table and field names in Directus 7 App or API?

Tags: rest, content-management-system, api-design, directus

I am trialling Directus 7 to build an API and replacement CMS on top of an existing MySQL database of some 10 years vintage. I have got the CMS and API up and running pretty easily, and it has found all my existing tables and fields. I have chosen to "manage" the relevant ones, and thus expose them to the API.

I don't want to expose the database structure directly in the API, nor the CMS UI either. But I can't see a way of mapping or transforming the existing MySQL table field names to API resource property names. The columns have a prefix convention which doesn't make sense when underscores are turned to spaces and it's also camel cased. I can't (won't) change the DB as there's a weight of code and configuration relying on it.

I noticed you can rename a field when assigning a UI (but not the "Display Name" directly) but all this does is create a new column in the DB. This is no good as I want to use the legacy columns.

I can't see any way of renaming a collection.

I've looked through the issues in both App and API, but can only see discussions around *translation* (ie. human language)
https://github.com/directus/app/issues/779 and 
https://github.com/directus/app/issues/422 which I guess might work, but this seems hacky.

Directus seems like a very powerful tool and easy to install on top of a legacy DB, but without a transformation layer I can't really use it.

If it really doesn't exist, then I will raise a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old and I hope you found an answer.
But since I came from Google and couldnt here is what I can do :

Let's say you have an column (legacy) "id_customer".
You want to use a relation...

Just create a new field with the same name column. It will fail, but the relation one for many (for example) will work.

It's a bit tricky, but I did not found a better solution.

Comment: I abandoned Directus as I didn't find a solution to this and a few other issues, so I can't verify your approach, but thanks for the update - hopefully someone else will find it useful one day.